# Could I use a Shimano GRX RX400 10-speed shifter with a Shimano Dura-Ace 7900 10-speed rear derailleur?

Tags: shimano, derailleur-rear, shifter, compatibility

I am trying to be budget friendly and recycle parts for a new project.

Answer (score 7):

The GRX ST-RX400 is compatible with the Tiagra RD-4700, which means it is using the 11-speed cable pull, making it **incompatible** with 10-speed road RD such as the Dura-Ace RD-7900.

Here is an excerpt from the [Shimano compatibility chart](https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/com?q=st-rx400&cid=C-453&acid=C-454):

[image]

And from [BikeGremlin RD compatibility article](https://bike.bikegremlin.com/1278/bicycle-rear-derailleur-compatibility/#1), about the Tiagra 4700 pull ratio:

> [...] Tiagra 4700 10 speed road RD – it has the same shift ratio as Shimano road 11 speed RDs [...] Another exception is the new “gravel” group (with hydraulic brakes): Shimano GRX. Cable pull wise it’s the same as Tiagra 4700.

Comment: Could you add a link to that compatibility chart?

Comment: @user2705196 I edited my answer to include it and the reference to the Tiagra 4700 cable pull ratio.